# Isolated points(poles) of Meromorphic functions are at most finite.

Tags: complex-analysis

By definition, each pole of any meromorphic function $f$ in a domain $D$ is isolated. This means if $z_o$ is a pole of $f,$ then there exists $r>0$ such that $f(z)$ is analytic in $B(z_o,r)-\{z_o\}.$ But how does this mean that the set of poles of $f$ is discrete? Kindly advise, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Discrete means just that. (A discrete set is a set such that every member is isolated.)

That doesn't mean that there has to be a *finite* number of poles (which you claim in the title of your question).  Finite sets are discrete, but the converse is not necessarily true. Take for example

$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{\sin \big(\frac{1}{z-1}\big)}, $$

which is meromorphic on the unit disc $D$, but still has an infinite number of poles (accumulating at $z=1$ which is on the boundary of $D$).

Comment: Thanks for the correction!